# Angular.js stops working anytime the Web Developer console in Firefox is open

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I have this very weird problem with Angular.js (1.2.27) **not working** when the web developer console is open in my Firefox browser and I refresh the page. It also happens when I open the web developer console whilst angular.js is working.

The way to get angular.js to work is to close the web developer console in FF and then refresh the page and 'hey presto [Bulwinkle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rocky_and_Bullwinkle_Show)...' it magically works.

Now my concern is why this is happening?

Also i'm using angular.bootstrap as follows and calling it or listening for when the user clicks a specific button on the page:

```
 var element = angular.element( document.querySelector('#my-angular-app') );

 if(element.length && angular){
    angular.bootstrap(element, ['myApp']);
 }
```

Any info or insight to as why this is happening would be swell. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

By the time angular is about to bootstrap your application `myApp`, it should have been already loaded into browser environment. So the order of the calls are important. (Found out after testing in Jsbin). I found this order works:

```js
angular.module('myApp', []);
//etc

var element = angular.element( document.querySelector('#my-angular-app') );

 if(element.length && angular){
    angular.bootstrap(element, ['myApp']);
 }
```

If you are trying to create the module after the execution of app bootstrapping, it will throw injecting error.

Comment: Yeah thats the weird thing as mentioned previously, myApp is already loaded. It's breaking only when the console is open in  or when the console is opened whilst myApp is running (in FF only).

Answer (score 0):

Found out it was a bug to do with 'FireQuery' for Firefox. I Simply disabled it and viola things started working again.